# html / code not working in static block to add price in a specific block?

Tags: magento-1, price, static-block, programmatically

I've tried multiple snippets of code to add an item price to a specific block without success.

On the example item page :

```
https://fixlcdscreens.com/default/catalog/product/view/id/10234/s/ACER-ASPIRE-V5-571-6868-15.6%22-Laptop-LCD-LED-Display-Screen/
```

I would like to add the product price in the right column block where I have put the text [INSERT PRICE HERE]

The following result happens from entering this code:

```
$this->getPriceHtml($_product, true);
```

[image]

The next snippet of code here results in the following :

```
<?php
    $productBlock = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product;
    echo $productBlock->getPriceHtml($_product);
    ?>
```

[image]

Can someone please help me achieve this in what you believe is the simplest way.
For reference I am trying to add the price (not move the original) to the block
identifier : `block_product_secondary_bottom`

Comment: You're calling PHP code in a static block? That won't work. Unless you are Ok to hard-code price in the block, you'll need to call a template atleast to display the prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not directly add the php code in the cms-block.

But you can call template and with in that template you can add php code. and create template  `app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/Yourtemplatepath/yourTemplate.phtml`

add this code

```
{{block type="core/template"  template="Yourtemplatepath/yourTemplate.phtml" }}
```

and add below code in template file `yourTemplate.phtml` file

```
<?php
$product = Mage::registry('current_product');
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_price');
echo $block->getPriceHtml($product);
?>
```

Comment: @d0pamine try this code and let me know and if its working for you then mark as accepted this answer , though I have tested this code and working fine for me.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I added the code to literally yourTemplate.phtml , and  added the file to /Yourtemplatepath/yourTemplate.phtml  ... but it is just showing the code in the file directly , check this page : https://fixlcdscreens.com/default/catalog/product/view/id/8226/s/HP-Pavilion-dv6-2023ax-Laptop-Screen-15.6-LED-BOTTOM-RIGHT-WXGA-HD-1366x768/category/6/

Comment: @d0pamine add php tag please check my updated answer

Comment: @d0pamine add `<?php` tag in `phtml` file before the code and add `?>` tag in end of the file , check my updated answer

Comment: EXCELLENT! WORKED! -- Can I ask you before I hit answered (in case it closes the post, can you tell me if I can add a line in the code to change the color/size of the price text?

Comment: @d0pamine its about the html and css based question. if you have basic knowledge about css you can change price size and color